# Создание XML в GWT

Tags: xml, gwt, java

Столкнулся с проблемой добавления значения к элементу. После выполнения следующего кода, значение нода не устанавливается.

```
Element tag = doc.createElement("tagElement");
tag.setNodeValue(stringValue);
```

Т.е. я хочу получить на выходе:

```
<tagElement>stringValue</tagElement>
```

А имею:

```
 <tagElement/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления текста, лучше использовать текстовую ноду.

```
Element tag = doc.createElement("tagElement");
tag.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(stringValue));
```

Comment: А GWT имеет оный метод?

Comment: Конечно.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, надо использовать setInnerText?

```
public static void setInnerText(Element elem,
                                java.lang.String text)

/* Sets the text contained within an element. 
If the element already has children, they will be destroyed. */
```

Comment: Думаю, он на самом деле делает то же самое (тоже создаёт text node). Однако, setInnerText выглядит понятнее..